# WebView suddenly shuts down

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I open a dialog when window.open command works in webview. So far everything is normal but I can access all the sites except TikTok (Instagram, YouTube etc) I get this error when TikTok opens;

```
2020-07-24 11:44:49.769 30452-30452/com.webdemo E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] 
Renderer process (30616) crash detected (code -1).
2020-07-24 11:44:49.818 30452-30452/com.webdemo E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(90)] 
Render process (30616) kill (OOM or update) wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing 
application.
```

my code;

```
webview1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            WebView nWebview = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
            transport.setWebView(nWebview);

            dialog.setPositiveButton("ÇIK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog create = dialog.create();

            create.setView(nWebview);
            nWebview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            WebSettings webSettings = nWebview.getSettings();
            nWebview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            nWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            Window window = create.getWindow();
            window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            nWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    Log.wtf("asdsa", url);
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }
            });
            nWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
                    create.dismiss();
                }
            });
            create.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    nWebview.destroy();
                }
            });
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            create.show();

            return true;
        }

    });
```

My English is a little bad, I'm sorry if I spell it wrong